# MariaDB versions: if statement differences

Tags: if-statement, mariadb

We have recently started work on migrating to a new server.

The current server is running MariaDB version 5.5.28.
The new server is running MariaDB version 5.5.47.

When we run these queries on MariaDB version 5.5.28, we get the same answer:
SELECT IF(1 < 2, 10, 20); . . . . . . . Answer: 10
SELECT IF(1 < 2, 10, 20.000); . . . Answer: 10

When run on MariaDB version 5.5.47, we get answers with different number of decimals:
SELECT IF(1 < 2, 10, 20); . . . . . . . Answer: 10
SELECT IF(1 < 2, 10, 20.000); . .  . Answer: 10.000

On version 5.5.47 what appears to be happening is even though the condition evaluates as true, the formatting of the false outcome (20.000) is being used to format the true outcome (10).

Any ideas why the query would return 10.000 instead of 10?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: MariaDB will use the datatype that can represent both data. In your case it is decimal. If you try `select if(1<2, 20, "test")` you will see that the result is a left-justified string `20` instead of right-justified number `20`. The previous behavior was considered a bug.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB 5.5.40 had "fixes for decimal type" -- I don't know whether that changed your use case and whether they thought it was a "fix", not a "break".

File a bug, if you like.

FWIW, MySQL 5.6.12 yields `10`.